# Как сделать запрет удаления дочерних записей foreign key?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Всем привет. Есть 2 таблицы(А-B),и они связаны fk(foreign key) по одному полю. Как сделать,чтобы при удалении родительского ключа с помощью ON DELETE CASCADE дочерний ключ не удалялся,и запись оставалась в таблице?

Comment: убрать _ON DELETE CASCADE_

Comment: Так тогда и ключа не будет. Мне надо привести базу к 3НФ

Comment: а какой результат вы ожидаете при удалении? что должно произойти? удалиться? выставиться какое-то значение? ничего не должно происходить? показывать ошибку? Если уберете _ON DELETE CASCADE_ то ключ останется, просто при попытке удаления строки, если на нее кто-то ссылается - будет ошибка

Comment: А отсутствие связи не помешает привести базу к 3-ей нормальной форме? 
Вообще,у меня 5 таблиц.
1-ая: ID товара;товар
2-ая: ID города;город
3-ая: ID поставщика;поставщик
4-ая: ID фирмы;фирма
5-ая: ID поставки;id товара ;id фирмы;id города;id поставщика;количество

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае подойдет [*ON DELETE SET NULL*](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/SEC451.html)

При удалении, значение будет установлено в *NULL*

---

Если вы просто уберете *ON DELETE CASCADE*

При удалении произойдет ошибка.